# Jquery .load() only for first 6 elements, with data-value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 7 html div's. How can i load some dynamically data only for first 6 div's using data-recentviewes as load-URL for each element?

html:

```
    <div id="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/123/"></div>
    <div id="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/456/"></div>
    <div id="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/789/"></div>
    <div id="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/321/"></div>
    <div id="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/654/"></div>
    <div id="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/987/"></div> <!-- 6 -->
---
    <div id="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/abc/"></div> <!-- dont load this -->
```

js (work only for first element):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var recentviewes = $("#recentViewes").data('recentviewes');    
    $("#recentViewes").each(function(index, element) {
        $("#recentViewes").load("http://example.com" + recentviewes);                   

        return index < 5;
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to remove (or amend) the `id` attributes as they need to be unique within the page.

Comment: ids are meant to be unique so getting `$('#recentViewes')` will only return the first element as it is not expecting any others.  Change the id to a class and use `$('.recentViewes')` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove (or amend) the `id` attributes as they need to be unique within the document context. This is why your code only works for the first element.

You should change them to `class` attributes instead. You can then use the `:lt` selector to select the elements you require:

```
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/123/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/456/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/789/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/321/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/654/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/987/"></div> <!-- 6 -->

<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/abc/"></div> <!-- dont load this -->
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    $(".recentViewes:lt(6)").each(function() {
        $(this).load("http://example.com" + $(this).data('recentviewes'));
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(".recentViewes:lt(7)").` should be `$(".recentViewes:lt(6)").` I think?

Comment: Best for me. Ill accept this answer in 2 min. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use class to group similar elements instead of ID since ID of an element must be unique

```
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/123/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/456/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/789/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/321/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/654/"></div>
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/987/"></div>
<!-- 6 -->---
<div class="recentViewes" data-recentviewes="/abc/"></div>
<!-- dont load this -->
```

then

```
$(window).load(function () {
    //get all elements with recentViewes class and take first 6 from that and loop
    $(".recentViewes").slice(0, 6).each(function (index, element) {
        //inside the loop use this to refer to the current recentViewes element and load the resource 
        $(this).load("http://example.com" + $(this).data('recentviewes'));
    });
});
```